# Open Liberty and Jersey servlet - 415 Unsupported Media Type

Tags: upload, jersey, multipartform-data, open-liberty

I'm working with OpenLiberty version 22.0.0.2 (no Jakarta Restful Web Services enabled).
I'm trying to implement a document upload API using the Multipart Feature Provided by Jersey.

I have tried numerous suggestions, but cannot get it to work.

**API**

```
@POST
@Path("/upload")
@Consumes(MediaType.MULTIPART_FORM_DATA)
@Produces(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
public Response upload(
        @FormDataParam("file") InputStream uploadedInputStream,
        @FormDataParam("file") FormDataContentDisposition fileDetail)
```

**Application**

```
@ApplicationPath("/")
public class RestApplication extends ResourceConfig {

public RestApplication() {
    register(MultiPartFeature.class);
    packages("com.packages.to.scan");
}
```

**pom.xml**

```
<dependency>
  <groupId>org.glassfish.jersey.containers</groupId>
  <artifactId>jersey-container-servlet</artifactId>
  <version>2.28</version>
</dependency>

<dependency>
  <groupId>org.glassfish.jersey.media</groupId>
  <artifactId>jersey-media-json-jackson</artifactId>
  <version>2.28</version>
</dependency>
<dependency>
  <groupId>org.glassfish.jersey.media</groupId>
  <artifactId>jersey-media-multipart</artifactId>
  <version>2.28</version>
</dependency>
```

The error I'm getting in OL when uploading a file via Postman:

```
[INFO] [ERROR] No message body reader has been found for class org.glassfish.jersey.media.multipart.FormDataContentDisposition, ContentType: multipart/form-data;boundary=--------------------------814467839830640328856820
```

Postman outputs [image]

What am I missing in the setup?